# Make all text in pdf slightly thicker/fatter. Like simulating dot-gain in offset printing?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, acrobat, outline, stroke

I would like to make all text in a pdf (from a customer) slightly thicker/fatter to simulate how it will look when printed (normal dot-gain) in a offset press.
If I use the PitStop-plugin in Acrobat I can convert all text to outline and then add a stroke to the outline so that it will be thicker/fatter.
However, those are manual steps and I need to automate it completely.

My thought was to go with GhostScript and I've managed to convert it to outline, but I cant find if there's a way to add stroke or something similar within GhostScript?

My current command is:

```
gs -o output.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -StrokeWidth=2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input.pdf
```

I've tried to add: -StrokeWidth=2 but that gave me no effect (I don't even know what kind of measure it wants)

Any ideas/solutions?

Best Regards
Niclas Rådström

Comment: There is no way to simply achieve what you want with Ghostscript. Even if there were, you would be altering the thickness of *all* strokes which would presumably cause your linework to look incorrect. Randomly adding stuff to the command line really isn't going to help, the valid commands are all documented.

Comment: One solution would be getting PitStop Server… Another way to try would be applying one of the "dot gain" ICC profiles. I am, however, not quite sure whether they work with vector data.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to insert a redefinition of the 'show' operator which strokes the outline of the character with a line width of your choice in addition to the regular show operation. But I agree with Max Wyss that something actually designed to address your problem like a dot gain profile would be a better bet.

/show{gsave dup true charpath .025 setlinewidth stroke grestore //show}def

Comment: Two problems; firstly this is a PDF file so it doesn't use the 'show' operator directly at all. Although the Ghostscript PDF interpreter does use show internally, I can't recall offhand if it uses the system one or not. Secondly, even if you override the 'show' operator, there are in fact 10 different show operators; show, ashow, widthshow, awidthshow, xshow, yshow, xyshow, glyphshow, kshow and cshow. You would have to define replacements for all of them.